# How to Format time in Yahoo PIpes to get the minutes past..?

Tags: php, twitter, yahoo-pipes

I fetched the tweets from twitter api using yahoo pipes.
Now, twitter gives the time in this format "Thu May 27 19:56:21 +0000 2010".
I want to know how many minutes have past since "Thu May 27 19:56:21 +0000 2010".
How, can i format "Thu May 27 19:56:21 +0000 2010" in order to get the minutes past?? in other words, i want to subract "now" and "Thu May 27 19:56:21 +0000 2010". Then convert the result into minutes.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

`$tweet_time = strtotime("Thu May 27 19:56:21 +0000 2010");

$minutes_since = (time() - $tweet_time) * 60;`

Comment: how am i suppose to use this yahoo pipes?? in Data formatter module or data builder module?? :(

Anyways, thanx a lot

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You had it tagged with PHP so I assumed you were coding with PHP. Not sure how Pipes works.

Comment: fine....its okay :)   Sorry to u too 'cus i tagged PHP in the "question tagged". Actually, yahoo pipes and php seems to have some common keywrds :)